# How do I validate that a Pandas method has been called?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, dataframe, mocking

I am trying to use unit testing to confirm that I have called a Pandas method. I have one simple line of code in a Jupyter notebook code cell, and I would like to test it and validate that it has been executed. I can do this visually of course, but I want to do it automatically using code. I have played with variations of **mock**, **patch** and **assert**, but I can't seem to get it to work. The name of my DataFrame is "cars". The code works well and I'm getting what I expect, I just need a way to validate that the method call was executed, *and* I'd like to verify that it was called with the DataFrame called "cars".

Here is my code:

**cars.info()**

Is there a simple way to validate that (1) this method was called and (2) that it used the "cars" DataFrame? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: this is called mocking. it's a bit of weird topic and it's pretty broad. lots of questions on stack overflow about it

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Comment: @PaulH I'm a noob with the logging module, but couldn't you just run a check with the logging module to see what was executed ?

Comment: @Datanovice No. I doubt any logging calls are built into the `.info` method, so you'd have to log around your calls to `DataFrame.info`. Then you'd have to inspect the logs, so all would be doing is testing that you logged something.

Comment: That's clear, thanks @PaulH

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but, can anyone please give me a code example, using my cars.info() method call, of what this would look like? Thanks again.

Comment: @RonMaratone Stack Overflow isn't really a code writing service. Read the documentation and try to ask a specific question. If you don't have time for that, I charge $50/hr for small jobs like this.